# Conditional Formatting in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to use conditional formatting in Google sheets for a work project. I want to get 3 different formats. Basically if columns F & H were blank were would highlight them red. If cell F was filled in but cell H was blank then we would highlight the cells yellow and if both cells F & H were filled in then we would highlight it green.

How can I do this in google sheets, with a nested if statement? I'm having trouble putting together the right formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mnv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Go to Conditional Formatting;
Select the range to which this will apply;
Then choose in Format cells if... Custom Formula;

Conditional Formatting 1:

```
=AND($F2="";$H2="")
```

Conditional Formatting 2:

```
=AND($F2<>"";$H2="")
```

Then you get the idea.

Comment: That worked beautifully thanks for the help! Do you mind please explaining how the formula's work? I'm not familiar with the  expressions used so I'd like to try to educate myself and understand what is going on in the formulas

Comment: Hi, @JohnK! Glad it worked! I'm not sure as to the reason why it doesn't require the formula syntax to be complete like we'd use in the cells, but it's the same principle though. The 
 comparison in a cell would be like: ```IF(AND($F2="";$H2="");"FORMAT";"DON'T FORMAT")...

Comment: Okay awesome I understand how it's working now seems pretty straightforward, thanks again for the help I really appreciate it!